# Is there a name for this poset?

Tags: order-theory

Is there a well-known name for the poset defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the comparison operator $(x_1, y_1) ≤ (x_2, y_2)$ iff $x_1 ≤ x_2$ and $y_1 ≤ y_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This order is sometimes called *product order*.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a name for it when the poset is $\mathbb{R}$ specifically?

Comment: I think there is no special name.

Comment: @garageàtrois It's sometimes called the lattice-order on the plane, or the coordinate-wise order.